# how to plot gradient fill on the 3d bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

Right now there're some statistics plotted in 3d bar over (x, y). each bar height represents the density of the points in side the square grid of (x,y) plane. Right now, i can put different color on each bar. However, I want to put progressive color on the 3d bar, similar as the cmap, so the bar will be gradient filled depending on the density.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# height of the bars
z = np.ones((4, 4)) * np.arange(4)
# position of the bars
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(np.arange(4), np.arange(4))

xpos = xpos.flatten('F')

ypos = ypos.flatten('F')

zpos = np.zeros_like(xpos)


dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = z.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')

plt.show()
```

Output the above code:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me first say that matplotlib may not be the tool of choice when it comes to sophisticated 3D plots.

That said, there is no built-in method to produce bar plots with differing colors over the extend of the bar.

We therefore need to mimic the bar somehow. A possible solution can be found below. Here, we use a [`plot_surface`](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) plot to create a bar that contains a gradient.

[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors 
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection= Axes3D.name)

def make_bar(ax, x0=0, y0=0, width = 0.5, height=1 , cmap="viridis",  
              norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1), **kwargs ):
    # Make data
    u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 4+1)+np.pi/4.
    v_ = np.linspace(np.pi/4., 3./4*np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, len(v_)+2 )
    v[0] = 0 ;  v[-1] = np.pi; v[1:-1] = v_
    x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

    xthr = np.sin(np.pi/4.)**2 ;  zthr = np.sin(np.pi/4.)
    x[x > xthr] = xthr; x[x < -xthr] = -xthr
    y[y > xthr] = xthr; y[y < -xthr] = -xthr
    z[z > zthr] = zthr  ; z[z < -zthr] = -zthr

    x *= 1./xthr*width; y *= 1./xthr*width
    z += zthr
    z *= height/(2.*zthr)
    #translate
    x += x0; y += y0
    #plot
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, **kwargs)

def make_bars(ax, x, y, height, width=1):
    widths = np.array(width)*np.ones_like(x)
    x = np.array(x).flatten()
    y = np.array(y).flatten()

    h = np.array(height).flatten()
    w = np.array(widths).flatten()
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=h.max())
    for i in range(len(x.flatten())):
        make_bar(ax, x0=x[i], y0=y[i], width = w[i] , height=h[i], norm=norm)


X, Y = np.meshgrid([1,2,3], [2,3,4])
Z = np.sin(X*Y)+1.5

make_bars(ax, X,Y,Z, width=0.2, )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually, rethinking about it, using spheric coorinates may not be the best idea; using cylindric coordinates may be more efficient. But I think the point comes across anyhow.

Comment: I was wondering it possible to do this example with a array or 81 value. I have an array of 81 value and I want to plot the 3d barplot with your progressive color gradient, in a (x,y)(9,9) mash grid.  My array is flux = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00523951, 0.00536901, 0.00533961, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...................],  which i reshape as data_2d = np.reshape(flux, (9,9)) for 9,9 array. How to get the bar plot like yours with a progressive color in each bar.Can you please guide? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please look into my comment above. I was wondering if this is possible. Can you please guide.