# Matplotlib Irregular 3d Polygon with Colormap, Is it possible to plot onto a patch?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, patch, colormap

I am trying to make a 3D, irregular octagon given vertex points. However, I want to colors on the octagon correlate to a completely separate variable, that has position arguments, but they are not in terms of the 3d octogon. 
Ideally, I would have hexbins generated separately on every side of the octagon but a colormap would also be appropriate.

Currently, to generate the 3D octogon I am using

```
topart = ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(vertstop, alpha = alpha))
botart = ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(vertsbot, alpha = alpha))
```

And the sides are generated with

```
sideart = ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(vertsside, alpha = alpha))
```

It really does not want me to add a color map, and it especially does not want me to make one based on this 4th variable. Is this even possible? I feel like it would be if there were a way to parameterize the octogonal space with some kind of meshgrid.

If I could somehow get a hexbin on a patch, then I would be set. Is it possible to plot onto a patch, or make a patch from something that has already been plotted?

[image: 3d oct]

Comment: check out scatter3D, or see if c = your_fourth_variable works https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html

Comment: Scatter 3D isn't really what I want here, I want the faces of the polygon to have gradients. Also 'c' is undefined for 3d.

Comment: Sounds like plot_surface(X, Y, Z, *args, **kwargs)  with the color = kwarg

Comment: I've tried plot_surface but my Z is not dependent on my X and Y and matplotlib gets very upset with me.

Comment: You may use a method similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119180/4124317). I.e. you may want to parametrize your surface to a grid. The solution for an octrahedron is of course a bit more complicated than for a bar but should still be possible.

Comment: The problem is I really need the info from all the sides. Can I save a colormap or hexbin as a patch?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem of using plot_surface in the way the linked answer does. It gives you a plot with the colors on all sides.