# How can I add a barcolor in a 3D barchart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable



result=[['4', '24', '16','22', '13'],
 ['13', '41', '25','31', '30'],
 ['83', '91', '83','98', '60']]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)

"""Se define lo que va a ser el dibujo o el plot"""
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=150)
#First subplot
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xlabels = np.array(['9','12','16a','16b','16c'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['ACN', 'ETOH', 'C-HEX'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2.)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

values = np.linspace(0.1, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])

ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz)

plt.show()
plt.savefig("ICT.png")
```

So, the thing is that I am not able to put a viridis colormap to my results and plot the colorbar in the right. Can anyone help me?
The result I obtain with this code is the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIsCA.png)

Comment: I marked this as duplicate of the thread from which the answer just copied the code. it may not be what you're after, in which case you may want to explain better the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question!

Some times matplotlib docs can be a bit confusing and the library may not be the greatest at 3D pretty plots. After looking at this thread ([how to plot gradient fill on the 3d bars in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100082/how-to-plot-gradient-fill-on-the-3d-bars-in-matplotlib)) and with some tweaks to your code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

result=[['4', '24', '16','22', '13'],
 ['13', '41', '25','31', '30'],
 ['83', '91', '83','98', '60']]

result = np.array(result, dtype=np.int)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection= Axes3D.name)

def make_bar(ax, x0=0, y0=0, width = 0.5, height=1 , cmap="viridis",  
              norm=matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1), **kwargs ):
    # Make data
    u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 4+1)+np.pi/4.
    v_ = np.linspace(np.pi/4., 3./4*np.pi, 100)
    v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, len(v_)+2 )
    v[0] = 0 ;  v[-1] = np.pi; v[1:-1] = v_
    x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
    y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
    z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

    xthr = np.sin(np.pi/4.)**2 ;  zthr = np.sin(np.pi/4.)
    x[x > xthr] = xthr; x[x < -xthr] = -xthr
    y[y > xthr] = xthr; y[y < -xthr] = -xthr
    z[z > zthr] = zthr  ; z[z < -zthr] = -zthr

    x *= 1./xthr*width; y *= 1./xthr*width
    z += zthr
    z *= height/(2.*zthr)
    #translate
    x += x0; y += y0
    #plot
    ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, **kwargs)

def make_bars(ax, x, y, height, width=1):
    widths = np.array(width)*np.ones_like(x)
    x = np.array(x).flatten()
    y = np.array(y).flatten()

    h = np.array(height).flatten()
    w = np.array(widths).flatten()
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=h.max())
    for i in range(len(x.flatten())):
        make_bar(ax, x0=x[i], y0=y[i], width = w[i] , height=h[i], norm=norm)


"""Se define lo que va a ser el dibujo o el plot"""
#fig=plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=150)
#First subplot
#ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xlabels = np.array(['9','12','16a','16b','16c'])
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array(['ACN', 'ETOH', 'C-HEX'])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])

xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos=result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

dx=0.5
dy=0.5
dz=zpos

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx/2.)
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels)

ax.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy/2.)
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

values = np.linspace(0.1, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])

#ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz*0, dx, dy, dz, shade=True, color=colors)

make_bars(ax, xposM, yposM, dz, width=0.2, )

plt.show()
```

I managed to get this result:

[image]

I suppose that's not yet what you need, but with the built-in custom functions you may be able to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!